# ICA - Statistical Independence & Eigenvalues of Covariance Matrix

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, statistics

I am currently creating different signals using Matlab, mixing them by multiplying them by a mixing matrix A, and then trying to get back the original signals using [FastICA](http://research.ics.tkk.fi/ica/fastica/).

So far, the recovered signals are really bad when compared to the original ones, which was not what I expected.

I'm trying to see whether I'm doing anything wrong. The signals I'm generating are the following: (Amplitudes are in the range [0,1].)

```
s1 = (-x.^2 + 100*x + 500) / 3000; % quadratic
s2 = exp(-x / 10); % -ve exponential
s3 = (sin(x)+ 1) * 0.5; % sine
s4 = 0.5 + 0.1 * randn(size(x, 2), 1); % gaussian
s5 = (sawtooth(x, 0.75)+ 1) * 0.5; % sawtooth
```

[image: Original Signals]

One condition for ICA to be successful is that at most one signal is Gaussian, and I've observed this in my signal generation.

However, another condition is that all signals are statistically independent.

All I know is that this means that, given two signals A & B, knowing one signal does not give any information with regards to the other, i.e.: P(A|B) = P(A) *where P is the probability*.

Now my question is this: **Are my signals statistically independent?** Is there any way I can determine this? Perhaps some property that must be observed?

Another thing I've noticed is that when I calculate the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix (calculated for the matrix containing the mixed signals), **the eigenspectrum seems to show that there is only one (main) principal component**. What does this really mean? Shouldn't there be 5, since I have 5 (supposedly) independent signals?

For example, when using the following mixing matrix:

```
A =

0.2000    0.4267    0.2133    0.1067    0.0533
0.2909    0.2000    0.2909    0.1455    0.0727
0.1333    0.2667    0.2000    0.2667    0.1333
0.0727    0.1455    0.2909    0.2000    0.2909
0.0533    0.1067    0.2133    0.4267    0.2000
```

The eigenvalues are: `0.0000    0.0005    0.0022    0.0042    0.0345` (only 4!)

When using the identity matrix as the mixing matrix (i.e. the mixed signals are the same as the original ones), the eigenspectrum is: `0.0103    0.0199    0.0330    0.0811   0.1762`. There still is one value much larger than the rest..

Thank you for your help.

I apologise if the answers to my questions are painfully obvious, but I'm really new to statistics, ICA and Matlab. Thanks again.

**EDIT -** I have 500 samples of each signal, in the range [0.2, 100], in steps of 0.2, i.e. `x = 0:0.1:100`.

**EDIT -** Given the ICA Model: **X = As + n** (I'm not adding any noise at the moment), but I am referring to the eigenspectrum of the transpose of X, i.e. `eig(cov(X'))`.

Answer (score 1):

Your signals are correlated (not independent).  Right off the bat, the sawtooth and the sine are the same period.  Tell me the value of one I'll tell you the value of the other, perfect correlation.

If you change up the period of one of them that'll make them more independent.

Also S1 and S2 are kinda correlated.

As for the eigenvalues, first of all your signals are not independent (see above).

Second of all, your filter matrix A is also not well conditioned, spreading out your eigenvalues further.

Even if you were to pipe in five fully independent (iid, yada yada) signals the covariance would be:

```
E[ A y y' A' ] = E[ A I A' ]  =  A A'
```

The eigenvalues of that are:

```
eig(A*A')
ans =

   0.000167972216475
   0.025688510850262
   0.035666735304024
   0.148813869149738
   1.042451912479502
```

So you're really filtering/squishing all the signals down onto one basis function / degree of freedom and of course they'll be hard to recover, whatever method you use.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Nate. I have some questions, if you don't mind. First of all, what do you mean by "five fully independent (iid, yada yada) signals". How would you know whether the signals are indeed independent? And what's (iid, yada, yada)?

Answer (score 0):

To find if the signals are mutually independent you could look at the techniques described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12047/multivariate-mutual-independence-test)  In general two random variables are independent if they are orthogonal.  This means that: E{s1*s2} = 0  Meaning that the expectation of the random variable s1 multiplied by the random variable s2 is zero.  This orthogonality condition is extremely important in statistics and probability and shows up everywhere.  Unfortunately it applies to 2 variables at a time.  There are multivariable techniques, but none that I would feel comfortable recommending.  Another link I dug up was this [one](http://www.commsp.ee.ic.ac.uk/~mandic/ASP_Slides/ASP_Lecture_1_Random_Variables.pdf), not sure what your application is, but that paper is **very** well done.

When I calculate the covariance matrix I get:

```
cov(A) =
 0.0619   -0.0284   -0.0002   -0.0028   -0.0010
-0.0284    0.0393    0.0049    0.0007   -0.0026
-0.0002    0.0049    0.1259    0.0001   -0.0682
-0.0028    0.0007    0.0001    0.0099   -0.0012
-0.0010   -0.0026   -0.0682   -0.0012    0.0831
```

With eigenvectors,`V` and values `D`:

```
[V,D] = eig(cov(A))

V =

-0.0871    0.5534    0.0268   -0.8279    0.0063
-0.0592    0.8264   -0.0007    0.5584   -0.0415
-0.0166   -0.0352    0.5914   -0.0087   -0.8054
-0.9937   -0.0973   -0.0400    0.0382   -0.0050
-0.0343    0.0033    0.8050    0.0364    0.5912
D =
0.0097         0         0         0         0
     0    0.0200         0         0         0
     0         0    0.0330         0         0
     0         0         0    0.0812         0
     0         0         0         0    0.1762
```

Here's my code:

```
x = transpose(0.2:0.2:100);
s1 = (-x.^2 + 100*x + 500) / 3000; % quadratic
s2 = exp(-x / 10); % -ve exponential
s3 = (sin(x)+ 1) * 0.5; % sine
s4 = 0.5 + 0.1 * randn(length(x), 1); % gaussian
s5 = (sawtooth(x, 0.75)+ 1) * 0.5; % sawtooth
A = [s1 s2 s3 s4 s5];
cov(A)
[V,D] = eig(cov(A))
```

Let me know if I can help any more, or if I misunderstood.

**EDIT** Properly referred to eigenvalues and vectors, used 0.2 sampling interval added code.

Comment: I used x = 0.2:0.2:100 (I've just added this detail to my original question - thanks for pointing it out.) How did you arrive at that covariance matrix? The covariance matrix for the mixing matrix A that I posted in the question is different. Also, using eig(cov(A)) gives you the eigenvalues, not eigenvectors, of the matrix. Apart from this, I was not referring to the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix of A, but the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix of the mixed signals. I'll add this to my question to make it clearer.

Comment: Oh and thank you for the link, but can you please explain further? Like I said, I'm a statistics newbie. I'd like to know if there is a general method that's used to check whether a number of signals are statistically independent or not.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however, it hasn't really gotten me anywhere. My problem wasn't that of calculating the eigenvalues, but more as to why the eigenvalues are what they are.. You can see that one of the eigenvalues is relatively large. I'd think that for statistically independent signals, the eigenvalues would be more or less equal, and I'd like to know if this true. Plus I still haven't found a concrete way to check whether my signals are independent or not.